# git list all authors last commit date in a project

Tags: git

I want to ask if there is a command in git that can list all authors names with the last date of their commit

(for example , author mike last commit was on feb, 2, 2017)

Im using git on mac iOS terminal and I'm a beginner in using git

thanks

Comment: I'm assuming by iOS you mean MacOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you pretty close. Save it and make it executable (chmod +x *filename*). Then, of course, execute it in your git project directory (./*filename*).

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for a in `git log --pretty="%an" | sort | uniq`; do git log --author="$a" --pretty="Author: %an Last commit: %ai" | head -n1; done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

I guess I should explain the strategy a bit. Essentially, we query git for all authors, then sort that list and winnow it down to unique entries:

```
`git log --pretty="%an" | sort | uniq`
```

Then for each of those unique authors, we do a git log for just that author and take only the top result, formatting it to our liking with --pretty:

```
git log --author="$a" --pretty="Author: %an Last commit: %ai" | head -n1
```

The rest is just the looping mechanism (bash's for loop). It didn't exactly work flawlessly for me, but reasonably close. Should be a good place to start tailoring it to your specific needs--enjoy!

NOTE: Added a couple of lines to the script related to IFS/SAVEIFS. This will fix the for loop breaking on author names with spaces in them, which is quite usual. Sorry to have missed that detail earlier.

Answer (score 7):

```
git log --pretty=%an%x09%ad | awk -F$'\t' '!seen[$1]++'
```

`%x09` is character code 9, i.e. `'\t'`.  `-F$'\t'` sets that as awk's field separator, `seen[$1]++` is zero only the first time.

`%an` prints the author's name, and `%ad` prints the date of authorship.

Comment: Ooh! Shiny! What does it do?

Comment: @jpaugh better?

Comment: @jthill :-) I realize you might be busy building cool things(tm), but this came up in the LQP queue. IMO, explanation takes this post from "correct" to "awesome."

Comment: @jpaugh ow.  guilty as charged, it should have been either a comment or done right the first time, thanks.

Comment: @jthill sure, if I resolve to do it. I investigated a little before you edited your answer above, and I saw enough that I [again] wasn't feeling very encouraged to chase this skill. Is there a resource you'd suggest to help make it approachable? This is the page I found that didn't clear up very much for me, though I concede the author tried pretty hard: https://www.quora.com/How-does-this-simple-awk-command-remove-duplicates

Comment: @jthill so, I spent some time with this and I found the explanation by Brian Bi (link in earlier comment) made sense to me--a big relief after I saw the first answer by the professor, which also has merit but is way more intimidating. Thanks for encouragement.

Comment: I really wanted to to mark this as useful - because it really should be the accepted answer - but it is still far too cryptically written to deserve points. What on earth does "seen[$1]++ is zero only the first time" mean? A couple of sentences explaining this (the answer is hardly very long at the moment) would be very useful for many of us - we should all be better at `awk` but this is a `git` question, and should have some more `awk` hand-holding.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to use the `pretty` format options to git to achieve this kind of thing.

In this case, you probably want something like:

```
 git log --pretty="%aD %an %ae"
```

`git log` will output in reverse chronological order by default, so the first occurrence of a name is their last commit. So on *nix systems, something like the following will get the line you want:

```
git log --pretty="Author: %an last commit: %ai" |grep "mike" |head -n1
```

Look at `man git-log` and the `PRETTY FORMAT` section for all the `%` macro options.

Comment: thanks but mike was an example, I want for all authors in the project, what should I modify ?

Comment: You'd need to wrap the output in something that picks out the first occurrence of each name, and then throws away the rest. What scripting languages do you have available? (not an iOS user so don't know the shell, installed languages etc).